# Как передать значение от валидации ActiveForm в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii

Как из валидации атрибута в ActiveForm вернуть в JavaScript значение, чтобы можно было его обработать?

```
public function validateCoupon($attribute)
{
    return 0.2;
}
```

Как понимаю, что нужно куда-то сюда копать, но не могу найти куда именно.

```
$('#test-form').on('afterValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, messages) {
    console.log(messages);
});
```

Либо можно как-то по-другому? Надо обработать на сервере купон и вернуть значение (скидку) в JavaScript, чтобы поменять цену и т.д. Естественно, чисто в рамках JS это тупо делать, так как код будет видно, вот надо на сервере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно проверять купон на сервере используйте ajax валидацию https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#ajax-validation